# django csrf_token in search result url

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Have csrf in search result url. Don't know why is there and how to remove it. Search works nice. Here is URL

```
/search/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=675d1340034e094866d15a921407e3fc&q=testing
```

here is view:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    rezult = []
    if query:
    qset1 = (
        Q(title__icontains=query) 
    )
    result = Product.objects.filter(qset1).distinct()
    if result.count() == 1:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(result[0].get_absolute_url())
    return render_to_response('search/search.html',{'query': query, 'result': result, },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thanks

Comment: @Aidan Ewen answer is the first correct

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remove `{% csrf_token %}` from your form in the template, you don't need it since you're making a GET request.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that csrf is not needed with GET request

Answer (score 4):

you added `{% csrf_token %}` in your form. if you dont need csrf remove this from your form and add csrf_exempt.

look at this sample of django:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
     return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you've added the `{% csrf_token %}` within one of the search form's `input` element. That would cause the token to be submitted along with the form.

Check your search form template.