# How to remove csrf token from search result url in Django?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, django-csrf

I am trying to implement a form for advanced search in django templates using crispy forms. But when I search and get redirected to the results page, I have the csrf token in the URL.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=EjwC5ExYEy8A9j4X9zAqXKIXrKSiApvoUeQYXgr0ieUJmo0m69uJY2zCLFaWz8Xe&name=test_csc&room=&form_index=
```

I do have a POST form later in the index.html file that I use a csrf token with, but even if I remove all instances of `{% csrf_token %}` anywhere, the url still has the csrf token in it.

I do not explicitly mention anything to do with csrf in my views file.

The advanced search in index.html:

```
<form action ="{% url 'app:search_results' %}" method="GET" id="form_index">
    <div class="form-group">
        {% crispy form_index %}
    </div>
</form>
<footer class="major">
    <ul class="actions special">
        <li><button type="submit" class="button" form="form_index" name="form_index">Search</button></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

I should mention that `form_index` is also used as a form to add something to the database. But I did create a separate form specifically for advanced search to test if it changed anything with the csrf in the url, and it didn't: it was still in the url with the separate form.

I have read the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/) concerning the csrf token. I haven't used `{% csrf_token %}` with a GET request. I have looked at and tried answers [Avoid CSRF token in URLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344101/avoid-csrf-token-in-urls), and [django csrf_token in search result url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050571/django-csrf-token-in-search-result-url), and [Using GET in a Django Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513857/using-get-in-a-django-form), which didn't solve my problem.

How to do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here in case someone has the same problem in the future. . .

In the [crispy form documentation](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html) there's a **disable_csrf = False** heading. All of my crispy logic and layout is in the `__init__()` function in the forms.py file. I just added `self.helper.disable_csrf = True` like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.disable_csrf = True
```

This fixed my issue.